# <Pet's name> loves you ♡

Tags: stardew-valley

I've been touching my cat for a while and just now a message appeared at the bottom-left corner (where all the other messages like "it's time to sleep" and "festival begins" appear). What does this mean for me and my cat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pets, like other animals, have a meter of how happy they are. For your pet this is hidden.

Pets don't produce items but there is a benefit to having a happy pet at the end of year 2 when

> Grandpa evaluates your performance. A pet that loves you is worth 1 point, which contributes to your rating.

Comment: note that [spoiler] can be re-evaluated at will if you have diamonds, so even if you miss the year-2 deadline you can try again.